# Ajax in Laravel procudes error 500 Internoal error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to fetch data in laravel with ajax get method. Every thing is ok, but when I make a Ajax request then request url is changes automatically.

For Example My url is `http://localhost/project/size/`. But, when Ajax request Call then url is change automatically like this
`http://localhost/project/size?idSize=4-small`  - after this 404 error is showing.And when using

```
url: "{{ route('size') }}"
```

Showing 500 Internoal error.
Here is My ajax code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectSize').change(function () {
            var idSize = $(this).val();
            if (idSize == "") {
                return false;

            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '/size',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { idSize: idSize },
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    alert(response);
                    var arr = response.split('#');
                    $('#getPrice').html("USD" + arr[0]);
                    $('#price').val(arr[0]);
                    if (arr[1] == 0) {
                        $('#cartButton').hide();
                        $('#Availability').text('Out Of Stock');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#cartButton').show();
                        $('#Availability').text('In Stock');
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    alert("Something Went Wrong, Please check again");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my contorller

```
//Here I Am getting Product Price
public function getProductPrice(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all(); 
    print_r($data);
    die();
    $proArr = explode("-",$data['idSize']);
    // echo $proArr[0]; echo $proArr[1];
    $proAttr = ProductAttribute::where(['product_id'=>$proArr[0],'size'=>$proArr[1]])->first();
    echo $proAttr->price;
    echo "#";
    echo $proAttr->stock; 
    // return $getCurrencyRates = Product::getCurrencyRates($proAttr->price);
    // echo $proAttr->price."-".$getCurrencyRates['USD_Rate']."-".$getCurrencyRates['GBP_Rate']."-".$getCurrencyRates['EUR_Rate'];
    // echo "#";
    // echo $proAttr->stock; 
}
```

My routes is

```
Route::get('size','ProductController@getProductPrice');
```

Comment: Is that route in the `api.php` or `web.php` route? Is it within a group of some kind?

Comment: quirel@ you there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use route `name()` then in ajax `router()` helper

```php
Route::get('size','ProductController@getProductPrice')->name('size');
```

then in ajax

```php
$.ajax({
url: "{{ route('size') }}",
```

then your ajax url will be always correct

Comment: Kamlesh Paul@you there?

Comment: kamlesh Paul@url: "{{ route('size') }}", showing 500 internol error